# Nunjucks twig embed

Tags: embed, nunjucks

I'm using twig to render templates in Symfony and nunjucks to render the same templates in JavaScript. Twig has an awesome feature called embed which is kind of a combination between include and extends. Is there a feature in nunjucks that works the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you've already found out that [this docs page](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html) contains all the needed information, which is that these two tags are supported:

> **include** pulls in other templates in place. It's useful when you need to share smaller chunks across several templates that already inherit other templates.
>
> **extends** is used to specify template inheritance. The specified template is used as a base template.

Just for those, wonering folks...

Comment: And no extensions either which implements it :( I think I have to implement it now.